# Command to test if players are on the same team

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to test if two players (actually, slimes, but it should work the same way) are on the same team. I have two teams, Nether and Ender, and I would like to see if a given slime is on the same team as the nearest player. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This will definitely require an `execute` command, and probably a scoreboard objective, but it's hard for me to come up with an exact solution right now.

Comment: You'll need a scoreboard for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give one of them a custom name:

```
entitydata @e[type=Slime] {CustomName:"Slime1"}
```

If you want, make the name invisible:

```
entitydata @e[name=Slime1,type=Slime,c=1] {CustomNameVisible:0}
```

You'll then need to create a clock with a bunch of commands in it, one for each team you're using. Each command follows this format:

```
execute @e[team=<team-name>,name=Slime1] ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[c=1,type=Slime,team=<team-name>]
```

### How it works

The `entitydata` commands both use `@e[c=1]` to return the nearest entity. The `c` argument makes it target only one of the entity, and always goes for the closest one.

The `execute` one targets a slime named "Slime1" on a specific team and tells it to test for another slime on the same team. Since you can only have one team tested at a time, you need seperate commands for each team.